# EMACS, Function call highlight

Tags: emacs, font-lock, emacs-faces

(EMACS 24.2 ) I need to highliight function call. I found this on internet

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda ()
   (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(
      ("\\<\\(\\sw+\\) ?(" . 'font-lock-function-name-face))t)))
```

It works but it highlight also the following open parenthesis.
I am non confident with regular expression, please, How can I modify match string to avoid parenthesis highlighting?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The regular expression is fine, you just need to highlight the first group in the match, not the whole of it. Replace `. 'font-lock-function-name-face` with `1 'font-lock-function-name-face`.

Another thing to change, just a recommendation, is that `font-lock-add-keywords` accepts the mode name as the first argument. So you don't need to use the hook.

Result:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
 'c-mode
 '(("\\<\\(\\sw+\\) ?(" 1 'font-lock-function-name-face)))
```